Why am I getting 404 NOT FOUND when using zuul?
I'm using springboot, zuul and eureka.
When I try to reach a springboot endpoint through a zuul service, I get 404 NOT FOUND.
I run all the services with docker containers.
Do anyone of you know what might be wrong?
The springboot service with the resouces (which I'm trying to reach through zuul) is called ContentService.
The endpoint in the ContentService I'm trying to reach
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/content")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class CommunityController {


    private CommuntiyService communtiyService;

    @Autowired
    private ACLverifier acLverifier;


    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/send_message/{message}")
    public void sendMessage(
            @PathVariable("message") String message
    ) {
        System.out.println("sent message: " + message);
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("commentExchange", "commentRoutingKey", message);
    }

Post request Im sending:
http://localhost:8080/cont/content/send_message/hallo

Response - 404 NOT FOUND:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-06-26T08:20:29.052+00:00",
    "path": "/cont/content/send_message/hallo",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "requestId": "2355b902"
}

ContentService
application.properties:
spring.application.name=ContentService
server.port=8082

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/test

# Use the database with:
# docker exec -it mongodb bash
# mongosh
# show dbs
# use <collection>
# db.<entity>.find()

# JWT
security.jwt.secret-key=3cfa76ef14937c1c0ea519f8fc057a80fcd04a7420f8e8bcd0a7567c272e007b
# 1h in millisecond
security.jwt.expiration-time=3600000

# rabbitmq
spring.rabbitmq.host=rabbitmq
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

# Eureka
# eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://eureka:8761/eureka}

# Actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

Application:
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class ContentServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ContentServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Eureka
application.properties:
spring.application.name=Eruka
server.port=8761

eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:8761/eureka
eureka.renewalPercentThreshold=0.85

Application:
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ErukaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ErukaApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Gateway/Zuul
application.properties:
spring.application.name=Gateway
server.port=8080

spring.docker.compose.enabled=false
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none


# Eureka
# eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://eureka:8761/eureka}


# Actuator
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.port=8080

# ===================================
# Zuul

# Content service
zuul.routes.content-service.serviceId=content-service
zuul.routes.content-service.path=/cont/**
zuul.routes.content-service.stripPrefix=true

Application:
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}

I run all the services with a docker-compose file:
version: '3.8'

services:

  # ============= GATEWAY ===============
  gateway:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: API_GATEWAY/DockerfileGateway
    container_name: Gateway
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - ms_architecture
  # ===================================

  # ============= EUREKA ===============
  eureka:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: API_GATEWAY/DockerfileEruka
    container_name: Eureka
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - ms_architecture
  # ===================================

    # ============= CONTENT SERVICE ===============

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - ms_architecture

  content_service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MicroServices/Content/ContentServiceDockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: mongodb://mongodb:27017/test
      RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
      RABBITMQ_PORT: 5672
    networks:
      - ms_architecture
  # ===================================


  # ============= RABBITMQ ===============
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - ms_architecture
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmqctl", "status"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3

  # ===================================

networks:
  ms_architecture:
    driver: bridge


Based on the Zuul and Spring MVC configurations you provided, your Zuul route configuration seems to be correct. However, there might be a conflict between the route path you configured in Zuul and the request mapping in your Spring MVC controller.
In your Zuul configuration, you've set zuul.routes.content-service.path=/cont/**, which means all requests starting with /cont/ will be routed to the content-service.
However, in your Spring MVC controller, you've set @RequestMapping("/content"). This means your controller will handle all requests starting with /content/.
So, when you send a request to http://localhost:8080/cont/content/send_message/hallo, Zuul routes the request to content-service and then content-service tries to find a handler that matches /content/send_message/hallo. However, based on your controller configuration, it's actually looking for a handler that matches /cont/send_message/hallo, hence you receive a 404 error.
One possible solution to this problem is to use the same path in both your Zuul and Spring MVC configurations. For instance, you could change your Zuul route configuration to zuul.routes.content-service.path=/content/** and then your request URL should be http://localhost:8080/content/content/send_message/hallo.
Another possible solution is to remove the /content prefix in your Spring MVC controller, and then your request URL should be http://localhost:8080/cont/send_message/hallo.
Try these solutions and see if they resolve your issue.

Thanks for the attempt at resolving the errors, but the errors were not resolved.
I tried changing the content-service.path to /content/** , and then calling
http://localhost:8080/content/content/send_message/hallo
i also tried removing the /content prefix in the controller, and then calling
http://localhost:8080/content/send_message/hallo
(where content-service.path was specified as /content/**)
None of these resolved the issue.

Change zuul.routes.content-service.path=/cont/** to zuul.routes.content-service.path=/content/** and then try again? Aligning it with the RequestMapping path sometimes works.
